# Using memory declared for other types

Tags: c, memory, types, malloc

If I were to initialize memory for a variable of four bytes, would I be able to point two two-byte variables to the memory stored for it?
I'm trying to further understand memory management and theoreitcs.

An example of what I'm taking about:

```
int main() {
    short* foo = malloc(4*(foo));    // sizeof(*foo)?
    /*in which sizeof will return 2 so I could say
      * malloc(20)
      * so could I say malloc(2*sizeof(long))?
      */
}
```

Or are types generally declared adjacent to each other on the heap, I.e. a block is reserved for long, and a block is reserved for short typed variables?

*Edit*
I forgot to include a question.
If I were to declare two variables of type short next to each other (an array), could I safely point a long to the first item, an and access both via bitmap? Obviously this is mainly for theoretics, as I feel that there would be better, more obvious answers to problems.

Comment: Memory doesn't know the meaning of the data it holds.

Comment: Yes `short *foo = malloc(4* sizeof *foo);` is probably intended here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. C doesn't care about types when you allocate memory - it's just a block of memory as big as you've requested. It'll let you write in it, over it, under it ... until something bad happens!

If you want neighbouring values an array is a good way to go:

```
int *myAllocatedArray = (int*)calloc(2, sizeof(int));

myAllocatedArray[0] = 100;
myAllocatedArray[1] = 200;
```

`calloc` will initialize every byte to 0.

Comment: Will calloc do exactly the same as malloc? And pointer arithmetic will work just fine?

Comment: @user2958652: Yes, `calloc` does exactly the same as `malloc` does. The difference being that it initializes the allocated memory to `0`. Sort of like calling `memset` on memory claimed using `malloc`

Comment: @user2958652 See my answer below according calloc() and malloc().

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you are able to access it as you want.
Little info from manual to calloc() and malloc():

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>

       void *malloc(size_t size);
       void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
       ...

DESCRIPTION
       The  malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to 
       the allocated memory.  The memory is not initialized.  If size is 0, 
       then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value
       that can later be successfully passed to free().
       ...
       The  calloc() function allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements 
       of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The 
       memory is set to zero.  If nmemb or size is 0, then calloc() returns 
       either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully 
       passed to free().
       ...
```

Comment: Endianess is irrelevant because 0x1234 is always 0x1234 regardless.

Comment: @Jocke Ok. When why do we need htons() and ntohs()?

Comment: `htons()` and `ntohs()` is required so that two computers easily can communicate to each other. It stands for Host to network endianess and Network to host endianess respectively. Locally it has really no effect. You shouldn't care about the byte order unless you read from a file which's format is specified to a specific endianess.

Comment: [mc]alloc() funcs are cross platforms. So if you write cross-platform program which uses low-level access to a memory then you should care about endianness because in different systems LSB (for instance) can be different. Do use htons() or ntohs()? Try them and you will see that even locally they has effect. And 0x1234 != htons(0x1234).

Comment: Endianess is totally irrelevant here. Memory is never addressed outside the computer.

Comment: @Michael A good blog post on the subject is the one about [the byte order fallacy](http://commandcenter.blogspot.se/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html).

Comment: @kqr Ok, thanks for the post link. I removed mention of endianness from my answer. But I cannot agree with the author's conclusion "...And neither should you, because byte order doesn't matter." from the provided blog post. I think it depends on task you solve. And sometimes it does matter. If you need examples or wants just to discuss it - we can move to some chat. If you really want to argue - we can try to make a call and discuss it in real-time.:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work, because malloc takes integer arguments like:
malloc(2*4), 4=sizeof(long), or anything like malloc(20);

Answer (score -1):

Yes, As stated by others, C is a weak-typed language. Which means that it has very little or no restrictions of type-conversions.

For example:

```
void *ptr;
unsigned int *m;
unsigned int *e;
double *d;

ptr = malloc(sizeof(double));

d = ptr;

m = ptr;
e = ptr + 6;

*d = 123.456f;

printf("mantissa: %u\nexponent: %u\ndouble: %f\n", *m, *e, *d);

/* Output:
 * mantissa: 536870912
 * exponent: 16478
 * double: 123.456001
 */
```

Comment: i = 12345 - here must be unrefencing (*i = 12345)?

Comment: Besides the fact `d` is a pointer so it should be `printf("%f\n", *d);` your code wouldn't print out `12345.0`!

Comment: Also the `printf()` would invoke undefined behaviour as `sizeof (*d)` is `8` and only `sizeof int` was allocated, which (most probably) is `4`.

Comment: And it still doesn't prints 12345.0. Because 12345 (int) not equals 12345.0 (double) in memory.